# cannot get sequelize instance methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

```
let userModel = sequelize.define('userModel',{
//Schema
},{
//options
    instanceMethods:{
        checkPassword(){}
    }
})
.........
async Login(){
    let ins = await userModel.findOne('xxx')
    ins.checkPassword // <= is not a function
}
```

it seems that instanceMethods didnt be loaded on `userModel.prototype`. while I `console.log(ins)`, `checkPassword` is existed in attribute `instanceMethods`.

how to call instanceMethods?

sequelize version:4.11.1

Comment: it works when i wrote ``userModel.prototype.checkPassword``. So how does options ``instanceMethods`` works?

Answer (score 0):

I just found in manual that in sequelize V4 class and instance methods are removed.

See in details. [breaking-changes](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-to-v4.html#breaking-changes)